# And_index should print indexes of and, but outputs weird things

Tags: python, python-3.x

Yeah, I'm not good at doing this. And_index should have printed indexes of "and" in input.

```
def ask():
  x = input("Enter your logical operation:")
  return list(map(str.upper, x.split()))

user_input = ask()

and_index = []


for i in range(0,len(user_input)):

  and_index.append(user_input.index("AND",i))
  and_index = list(set(str(and_index)))




print(and_index)
```

Input: 1 and 1
Output: 1 (index of and out of the input list)
Actuall output: ['[', ' ', '0', "'", ']', '1', ',']

In that case the input was: and and

Comment: what weird things does it print?

Comment: Enter your logical operation:and and
['[', ' ', '0', "'", ']', '1', ',']


Process finished.

Comment: Could you update your question with a sample input, your expected output and your actual output?

Comment: why do you append to `and_index` then on the next line totally overwrite it?

Comment: When changed does the same.Enter your logical operation:And hsh and hssh AND HDHD AND
['[', '4', '6', '0', ']', '2', ',', ' ']


Process finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not quite clear from your question what exactly you are trying to achieve. However it seems you want to get the indexes of some substring in your main string. below is a general function that will take a string and a substring and return back to you a list of start indexes where your substring was found

```py
def get_indexes_of_substring(input_string: str, substring: str) -> list:
    i = 0
    indexes = []
    while i < len(input_string):
        try:
            index = input_string.index(substring, i)
            indexes.append(index)
            i = index + len(substring)
        except ValueError as ve:
            break
    return indexes

user_input = "lowercase and, uppercase AND, mixedcases anD aND And ANd AnD aNd"
substring = "AND"
indexes_of_substring = get_indexes_of_substring(user_input.upper(), substring)

print(f'we found {len(indexes_of_substring)} instances of {substring}. These can be found at the following indexes:')
substring_len = len(substring)
for index in indexes_of_substring:
    end = index + substring_len # Note end is actually the index after the end of the word so it works with slices
    print(f'index: [{index}:{end}], word: {user_input[index:end]}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
we found 8 instances of AND. These can be found at the following indexes:
index: [10:13], word: and
index: [25:28], word: AND
index: [41:44], word: anD
index: [45:48], word: aND
index: [49:52], word: And
index: [53:56], word: ANd
index: [57:60], word: AnD
index: [61:64], word: aNd
```